# AWS Elasticbeanstalk Single Instance Force SSL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, amazon-web-services

I'm using aws elasticbeanstalk single instance for my application. I tried all solutions to force ssl. I mean even though user goes to http://myapp.com i want it to redirect https://myapp.com. I tried all mod_rewrite .htaccess solutions and also i tried to redirect by using php redirect function in my codeigniter controller and they didn't work.

Here is my .htaccess configuration:

```
#Force SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had followed the AWS docs, every call from port 443 is proxyed to port 80. Exclude localhost and it should work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR}   !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This worked for me. I have deployed my PHP application to Elastic Beanstalk as a single instance. I also used the instructions in this file - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html. So the above answer and the instructions in the link force an HTTP request to my application to HTTPS through htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Comment: It gives same problem. Redirect loop detected error. I think it's a problem based on aws elasticbeanstalk but i dont know where.

Answer (score 0):

Force HTTPS rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !status https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: No, both "https://" and "http://" are unreachable now. Normally, it works but after adding these redirect rules, it gets broken.

Comment: Then it might be reasons beyond what we see in the question. Since my suggested rule is only affecting `http://` traffic.

Comment: So, what should i do in this situation.

Comment: It is awfully late here. Last comment before I goto bed, run your request in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab. Also try to use a new browser. If nothing works then enable `RewriteLog` and go through its report.

Comment: Did you get any more debugging info?

Comment: No, it's still same. It gives redirect loop error. I tried RewriteLog but it didn't work in my EC2 instace.

Comment: Without any more detailed info it is difficult to guess what the problem is. You will need to contact an admin of your host